# How does Context.Value(key interface{}) interface{} work?

Tags: go

Please see the below code

```
import (
    ...
    "context"
    ...
)

type myStruct struct {
    ID  string
    Sig string
}

mySig := myStruct{
    ID:  "12345678",
    Sig: "Secret_Signature_Token",
}

// Setting a Value associated with a Key in Context
_ := context.WithValue(ctx, "myKey", &mySig)           -- 1

//Getting the same value
value, ok := ctx.Value("myKey").(*myStruct)            -- 2
```

Now, my question is: what is the use/meaning of `.(*myStruct)` in the above expression number 2
Could someone please explain the statement number 2 step by step.

Comment: https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 . Redo the whole Tour.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the value returned by `context.WithValue`?

Comment: @Fimzy, It is a sample code snippet. :)

Answer (score 4):

`ctx.Value("myKey")` returns an interface. So `.(*myStruct)` does a type assertion to convert it to the type `*myStruct`. So the `value` on the left hand side is of type `*myStruct` and you can access its fields e.g. `value.ID`.

A version of your example can be seen here: https://play.golang.org/p/Eg0v3vuSi6y